# Execute multiple commands in one line inside unix shellscript

Tags: shell-script, bash-scripting, centos-6

The question is somewhat related to the question asked here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130847/shell-multiple-commands-in-one-line, but the difference is, I need to execute the whole commands whether or not the commands are successful or not. So I presume, `&&` is not an option right?
Can I use `;` separated commands and `eval` or `bash`; 
something like

`eval cd /home/user/homedir ; /home/user/homedir/sbin/daemon.sh --config /home/user/homedir/etc/dd2 --script /home/user/homedir/sbin/dd3 start action1`

or something like that?

Please advise,

Comment: Is `/home/user/homedir/sbin/daemon.sh --config /home/user/homedir/etc/dd2 --script ` `/home/user/homedir/sbin/dd3 start action1` all one command?  What can you tell us about what `/home/user/homedir/sbin/daemon.sh` does?  (Also, why do you want to `cd` to `/home/user/homedir` and then use full pathnames?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

';' works. You could also use '&', simplified like this:

/home/user/homedir/sbin/daemon.sh --config & /home/user/homedir/etc/dd2 --script & /home/user/homedir/sbin/dd3 start action1

(Simultaneous execution, see comment for clarification below)

Comment: That would run the two commands _simultaneously_ in separate processes.  (1) This doesn't sound like what was asked for.  (2) This almost ***never*** makes sense when the first command is a `cd`, because it means that the second command won't get the benefit of the `cd`; i.e., it will run in whatever directory the user (the shell) is in when the command is typed, and not in `/home/user/homedir`, as seems to be intended.

Comment: For simultaneous execution, then: cd /home/user/homedir; /home/user/homedir/sbin/daemon.sh --config & cd /home/user/homedir; /home/user/homedir/etc/dd2 --script & cd /home/user/homedir; /home/user/homedir/sbin/dd3 start action1

Comment: yup, Scott is correct. As Sectio Aurea pointed out we should use the multiple cd to execute the scripts simultaneously.

Comment: Somebody is confused.  The question gives the appearance that `~/sbin/daemon.sh ––config ~/etc/dd2 ––script ~/sbin/dd3 start action1` is ***one*** command.  I asked the OP for confirmation and got no indication to the contrary.  But the above answer has taken this command and broken it into three parts.  _This is not an answer to **this** question, as stated._  Neither `grep; Scott; /etc/passwd` nor `grep& Scott& /etc/passwd&` will display my user ID information.

Comment: You're right technically. It's possible that it's one command but didn't seem at all likely - looking more like a naive use of bash. I answered based on that hunch about the 'real question' and expected the OP to correct me if that wasn't useful.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is fine, except I would leave off the `eval` unless you have some reason for having it (I don't see any reason).